# How to I tell my JAXB output to include a reference to the XSD that created it?

Tags: jaxb, xsd

Here is my pages.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:mac="http://www.tvworks.com/tva/xml/ns/max/data-types" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

 <xs:import namespace="http://www.tvworks.com/tva/xml/ns/max/data-types" 
            schemaLocation="http://developer.tva.tvworks.com/xml/ns/max/data-types-3.2.xsd"/>


 <xs:element name="data">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="scenes" type="scenesType"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>

 <xs:complexType name="scenesType">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="page" type="mac:page-ref"/>
     </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is my pages.xjb

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          version="2.1">
    <bindings schemaLocation="pages.xsd" version="1.0"">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="com.mycompany.pages"/>
        </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Here is what I want the output to look like, notice the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="pages.xsd"`.

```
<data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="pages.xsd">
 <scenes>
  <row>
   <page>page1</page>
  </row>
  <row>
   <page>page2</page>
  </row>
    <row>
   <page>page3</page>
  </row>
    <row>
   <page>page4</page>
  </row>
 </scenes>
</data>
```

**How do I get that attribute onto the `data` element the JAXB output automatically?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set property `jaxb.noNamespaceSchemaLocation` with the desired value on your `Marshaller`.

EDIT: check the section on supported properties in the [Marshaller documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html) as well as [method setProperty](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) for additional info.

Comment: +1 - For more information the property see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-java-io-files-streams-readers.html

Comment: Ah, there's class constants! Even better. Then use `Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION` instead of the plain String as property key, like Blaise shows in his blogpost.